# Call a function on state change *and* on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, usecallback

I have a table I need to generate based on 4 inputs. The inputs need to be filled out and then a button must be clicked for the table to generate. Also, the table should re-generate if the page is changed. So basically, I need the function to run **only** when the button is pressed or the pages change.

Because of pagination I have implemented useEffect/useCallback. The issue however is with the useCallback. Because the 4 inputs are passed to useCallback as a dependency, the table generates before I click the button and I don't want that to happen. I cannot remove the inputs as a dependency.

I could add another state, change the state after the button is pressed and add that state as a dependency in useEffect, so that each time I press the button, state is changed therefore useEffect is called -> table gets rerendered. This occurred to me but I am not sure I want to add another state to the mix as it seems wasteful.

The 4 inputs are passed through from the parent component as props.

How do I:

1. Prevent the generateTable from exectuing before I click the button
2. Execute generateTable after the button click

The code:

```
const Table: FC<Table> = ({ values }) => {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

  const [getData, getDataResponse] = useLazyQuery<
    IQueryResponse,
    IQueryInput
  >(QUERY_NAME), {
    fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
    onError: error => {},
  });

  const handleButtonOnClick = () => {
    generateTable();
  };

  const handlePageChange = (_event: unknown, value: number) => {
    setPage(value);
  };

  const generateTable = useCallback(() => {
    if (
      values?.input1 &&
      values?.input2 &&
      values?.input3 &&
      values?.input4 
    ) {
      getData({
        variables: {
          input1 : values.input1,
          input2 : values.input2,
          input3 : values.input3,
          input4 : values.input4,
          limit: rowsPerPage,
          offset: rowsPerPage * (page - 1),
        },
      });
    }

  }, [getData, page, values]);

  useEffect(() => {
    generateTable();
  }, [generateTable, page]);

  .
  .
  .
  
  return (
    <Button onClick={handleOnclick}>Generate table</Button>

    {getDataResponse.data ? (
      <Table> ... </Table>
      <Pagination page={page} onChange={handlePageChange} />
    ) : ''}
  )
```

Comment: You're running it the second you call it, you could possibly define the arrow function globally and call useCallback(newfunction(),[getData,page, values]);

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem by simplifying the code and getting rid of the useEffect and useCallback hooks entirely and just passing the value that required the useEffect before.

```
const Table: FC<Table> = ({ values }) => {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

  const [getData, getDataResponse] = useLazyQuery<
    IQueryResponse,
    IQueryInput
  >(QUERY_NAME), {
    fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
    onError: error => {},
  });

  const handleButtonOnClick = () => {
    generateTable(page);
  };

  const handlePageChange = (_event: unknown, value: number) => {
    setPage(value);
    generateTable(value)
  };

  const generateTable = (page: number) => {
    if (
      values?.input1 &&
      values?.input2 &&
      values?.input3 &&
      values?.input4 
    ) {
      getData({
        variables: {
          input1 : values.input1,
          input2 : values.input2,
          input3 : values.input3,
          input4 : values.input4,
          limit: rowsPerPage,
          offset: rowsPerPage * (page - 1),
        },
      });
    }
  }

  .
  .
  .
  
  return (
    <Button onClick={handleOnclick}>Generate table</Button>

    {getDataResponse.data ? (
      <Table> ... </Table>
      <Pagination page={page} onChange={handlePageChange} />
    ) : ''}
  )
```